# How to interpret buffer-display-time values?

Tags: time-date

I am trying to use `buffer-display-time` var, in order to come with a solution for [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/31786/can-ibuffer-show-buffers-last-viewing-time).

Having a look at the documentation, I get this:

```
buffer-display-time is a variable defined in ‘buffer.c’.
Its value is (23883 19206 790941 600000)
Local in buffer buffer.c; global value is nil

  Automatically becomes permanently buffer-local when set.

Documentation:
Time stamp updated each time this buffer is displayed in a window.
The function ‘set-window-buffer’ updates this variable
to the value obtained by calling ‘current-time’.
If the buffer has never been shown in a window, the value is nil.
```

How do I interpret these values `(23883 19206 790941 600000)` as a timestamp?

---

NOTE: That variable is defined in `buffer.c` as:

```
  DEFVAR_PER_BUFFER ("buffer-display-time",
             &BVAR (current_buffer, display_time), Qnil,
             doc: /* Time stamp updated each time this buffer is displayed in a window.
The function `set-window-buffer' updates this variable
to the value obtained by calling `current-time'.
If the buffer has never been shown in a window, the value is nil.  */);
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are asking how to tell, as a human, what corresponds to a time-date value such as `(23883 19206 790941 600000)`.

`(current-time-string '(23883 19206 790941 600000))` tells me that it's `"Wed Aug  7 15:04:54 2019"`.

How did I find this? I used `C-h i Elisp` followed by `i time TAB` and chose candidate `time value`.  That took me to this node of the manual: [(elisp) `Time of Day`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Time-of-Day.html), where I found function `current-time-string` described.

(Ask Emacs...)

Comment: I would have expected to get something like a current Unix timestamp of about 1565221420 (at least around 156522XXXX). But it seems Emacs does not work in the general common sense way...

Comment: `(time-to-seconds buffer-display-time)`

Answer (score 0):

A time stamp `(HIGH LOW USEC PSEC)`, such as the one returned by
`buffer-display-time`, gives enough information to determine the number of
seconds elapsed since 1970-01-01 00:00:00.  That number is computed as

> HIGH * 2^16 + LOW + USEC * 10^(-6) + PSEC * 10^(-12)

This is explained in the documentation of the function `current-time` where it is stated that

- HIGH has the most significant bits of the seconds
- LOW has the least significant 16 bits
- USEC and PSEC are the microsecond and picosecond counts

Comment: yep, that is what is shown in the link provided by @Drew